# Android: change TextView textColor when parent is focused

Tags: java, android, focus, themes

I have a `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout` is able to receive focus, and I want the `textColor` of the `TextView` to change when it does. I thought using a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) would work, but it would seem that the `TextView` does not receive focus when the `LinearLayout` does. I know that, because I have tried this code:

```
mTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Changed TextView focus to: " + hasFocus);
    }
});
```

And nothing gets logged. I don't want to use an `OnFocusChangeListener` on the LinearLayout to change the `textColor` of the `TextView`, I think this has to be done from XML. The reason for that is because in another activity I have an `ExpandableListView` with a custom adapter and custom views and Android changes the `textColor`s of the `TextView`s (from light to dark) inside my custom views when items are focused.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an old post, but since I had the same problem, here is the XML attribute I found to do this :

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

(to be added to the TextView to change its "focused" state when the Layout's state changes)

Comment: worked like charm :)

Answer (score 4):

You can fetch yout TextView in the onFocuseChange method of LinearLayout's listener. Something like

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    tv.setTextColor(R.color.foo);
}
```

Since your LL can host multiple widgets I think it's expected that onFocus of the LL will not propagate even if you have a single control

Comment: I know I can do it that way, but as I said in the original post, I would like to avoid it. Also, if you have ever used a custom adapter for a ListView you would see that it still changes the text color when focusing a list item, no matter how many elements you have inside an item view. I'm curious how they did that, and I'll bet it's done from XML only.